# Is there a complete list of binary codes for colors?

Tags: assembly

I'm wondering if there's a list of binary codes with the color names next to them? I'm going to use it in assembly language as instructed by our teacher.

I tried to use hexadecimal in assembly language, but I can't really figure it out. So, yea...

Edit: He showed us an example like this "0101011" and that showed up in DOSBOX as a green color.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a "binary code" for a color... because there's at least a dozen different schemes you could be referring to, e.g. 1980s-era BASIC colors, ANSI terminal colors, X11 colors, CSS colors, ColourLovers.com colors, etc...

Comment: “So, yea …” what does that mean?  This is unclear (with *many* interpretations), please provide an example: “a list of binary codes with the color names next to them”

Comment: My bad, I wasn't clear. He showed us an example like this "0101011" and that showed up in DOSBOX as a green color.

Comment: Here's a list of [web colour names](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/Farbe/Farbpaletten#Farbnamen_.28alphabetisch.29), but I think that's not really what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you talking about VGA text-mode colors?  You mentioned DOSBox but you didn't specify what mode or context withing an IBM-PC compatible you're talking about.  (And you only tagged this [assembly], which doesn't even imply x86.  Literally all CPUs and microcontrollers run machine code that could be written in assembly language, including modern web browsers.  And image/video editing software that works with YUV colors instead of RGB ...)

Answer (score 2):

Although there are so many other possibilities the one in most common use today is probably the standard web 24bit colour pattern which are hexadecimal numbers in the form 0xRRGGBB where 00=0 and FF=max. The [W3 colour picker](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) might approximately do what the OP wants even if so many other answers are possible.

ISTR Pantone have named a large number of possible 24bit RGB colours with fancy names but the names are so unmemorable as to render it completely useless! What is the point of PaleCream, SourMilk or HoneyWhite (I made these up but just look at any paint tin for shades of not quite white).

However, the binary code that the OP has posted in a comment as being green looks to me like some antediluvian IBM XT DOS CGA display - in fact probably this one [IBM XT DOS colours](https://opensource.com/article/21/6/freedos-sixteen-colors).